# Android not receiving broadcast UDP, but receiving directed UDP

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, broadcast

I'm having an issue where my Android device (An HTC Incredible running stock 2.3.4 rom) is not able to receive a broadcast UDP, but when I get the IP of the device (on the same network) and send the packet directly to the IP, the phone immediately recognizes it and interprets it.  I have tested with WireShark on two unrelated PCs, one not even on the same switch on this network, and both are able to see the packet (though they do call the packet "malformed") Yet the phone never receives (it doesn't require any data from the packet) so I'm wondering what's happening.

The same thing is happening in the emulator as well.

This is the current code.

```
                m_UDPSocket = new DatagramSocket( 9000 );
                m_UDPSocket.setBroadcast( true ); // unneeded?
                boolean finished = false; 

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

                m_UDPSocket.setSoTimeout( 1000 );
                do {

                    finished = true;
                    try 
                    {
                        m_UDPSocket.receive(packet);    
                    }
                    catch ( SocketTimeoutException  e )
                    {
                        finished = false; 
                        System.out.print( "Socket recieve timed out" );                             
                    }

                } while( finished == false );
                System.out.print( buf );
                InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();
```

So is my phone rejecting the UDP broadcast packets for some reason, any way to test that it is receiving the packet on my phone?   Is this the HTC Incredible issue [HTC issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8407) , and I need to program around this?

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me on this matter.

Comment: you need a multicast address (or broadcast), both are special addresses and the broadcast is (sub)network dependent http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address

Comment: I am using a broadcast address. Both machines I was testing the receiving on was able to see it at the same time, and it was sent on 192.168.78.255, which is our subnet.

Comment: Are the machines connected with an ethernet cable or via wifi?

Comment: @bestsss he doesn't need a multicast address, as he isn't doing multicast, and he doesn't need a broadcast address, as he is the receiver. It is the sender who needs the broadcast address.

Comment: @EJP, exactly I thought it was the sender, or not using multicast on the receiver

Comment: Machines are connected via Wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the HTC Incredible issue HTC issue

Looks very much like it.

> and I need to program around this?

You can't, other than by relying on broadcast.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a [multicastlock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html) . It seems that your phone is ignoring the packets that are not addressed to him directly (as a broadcast would be).

The answer is kind of late...but maybe it helps somebody that has the same issue. :)